# Accessing Spark in Azure HDInsights via JDBC

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm able to connect to hive externally using the following URL for a HDInsight cluster in Azure.

```
jdbc:hive2://<host>:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/
```

However, I'm not able to find such a string for spark. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-port-settings-for-services#spark-ports) says the port is 10002, but its not open externally. How do I connect to the cluster to run SparkSQL queries through JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

There is not one available.  But you can vote for the feature at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight/suggestions/14794632-create-a-jdbc-driver-for-spark-on-hdinsight.

Comment: This is not about the driver. The Spark port 10002 is not open or routed through 443 unlike hive.

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight is deployed with a gateway. This is the reason why HDInsight clusters out-of-box enable only HTTPS (Port 443) and SSH (Ports 22, 23) communication to the cluster. If you don' t deploy the cluster in a virtual network (vnet) there is no other way you can communicate with HDInsight clusters.  So instead of Port 10002 Port 443 is used if you want to access the Spark thrift server. If you deploy the cluster in a vnet, you could also access the thrift server via the ip address it is running on (one of the headnodes) and standard port 10002. See also public and non-public ports in the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-port-settings-for-services)